# java Sqlit delete did't work

Tags: java, php, sqlite

here is my code i debug and checked a lot but i did't get why this not  working. Please help me some one.

```
   if (msg.equals("succes")) 
  {
   Connection c = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
   c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\pk\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\HRMS\\employee.sqlite");
   c.setAutoCommit(false);
   stmt = c.createStatement();
   String sql = "DELETE FROM attendance";
   stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
   stmt.execute(sql);
   System.out.println(sql);
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "data are sent to server and deleted from local sqlite");
   rs.close();
   stmt.close();
   c.close();

  } 
   else 
  {
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg);
  }
```

Comment: What is the behavier do you have? Any Exception?

Comment: What do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `c.setAutoCommit(false);` in your code which means the delete statement is not commited to the database. Change this to 'true' or add a commit statement to resolve this.